# Why doesn't my sheet add new rows of data, after adding formulas to the spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a web app to track the working hours of employees at my company, the web app is simple, it just asks employees to enter their entry time when they arrive to work and the time when they leave. I have them enter first, their ID number and a password, then they just fill out the date, the time at which they arrived/left and I added a string for any other details they would like to add. Bringing this data to a google spreadsheet, as seen in the picture. What I want to do is add a VLOOKUP function, in the column that says "Name", that will search for the employees name by looking up their ID number in a data base, the problem is once I add the formula to the column labeled "Name", the spreadsheet stops receiving new data from the web app. Here's a link to a copy of the sheet (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fjpKRi3k0VQ8MOoa5ruCZurXcz6vmVsQt2g3NbELSJA/edit#gid=1409321990) and an here is the simplified the JavaScript and HTML code.

```js
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Form');
}
  
function AddRecord(DateEntry, username, ArrivalTime, ExitTime ) {
  
  // get spreadsheet details
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fjpKRi3k0VQ8MOoa5ruCZurXcz6vmVsQt2g3NbELSJA/edit#gid=';
  //Paste URL of GOOGLE SHEET
  var ss1= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var webAppSheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName('ReceivedData');
  const Lrow = webAppSheet1.getLastRow();
  
  const sep_col = 2;
  const data = [DateEntry, username, ArrivalTime, ExitTime, new Date()];
  const data1 = data.slice(0,sep_col);
  const data2 = data.slice(sep_col,data.length);
 
  const start_col = 1; 
  const space_col = 1;
  webAppSheet1.getRange(Lrow+1,start_col, 1, data1.length).setValues([data1]); 
  webAppSheet1.getRange(Lrow+1,start_col+data1.length + space_col, 1, data2.length).setValues([data2]);        
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <title>Time Tracking</title>
    <script>
    function AddRow()
    {
      var DateEntry = document.getElementById("DateEntry").value;
      var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
      var ArrivalTime = document.getElementById("ArrivalTime").value;
      var ExitTime = document.getElementById("ExitTime").value;
      google.script.run.AddRecord(DateEntry, username, ArrivalTime, ExitTime);
      document.getElementById("DateEntry").value = '';
      document.getElementById("username").value = '';
      document.getElementById("ArrivalTime").value = '';
      document.getElementById("ExitTime").value = '';
    }
    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">

<div class="header">
<h2>Time Tracking</h2>
</div>
    
    <div>
    <label>ID</label><br>
    <input class="field" id="username" type="text">
    </div>

    <div>
    <label>Date</label><br>
    <input class="field" type="date" id="DateEntry" />
    </div>  
    
    <div >
    <label>Arrival Time</label><br>
    <input class="time" type="time" id="ArrivalTime" /><br>
    </div>
    
    <div > 
    <label>Exit Time</label><br>
    <input class="time" type="time" id="ExitTime" /><br>
    </div>
    
    <div class="btn">
    <button type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddRow()">Send</button>
    </div> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation / Issue:

The issue is that you are using an `arrayformula` which expands until the **last** available row in the sheet.

- However, your goal is to append a new row everytime after the last row with content.
- Therefore, by using `getLastRow` you are getting the wrong row.
- Instead of using `arrayformula` use a single `vlookup` formula and
  take advantage of [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in order to dynamically
  change the `vlookup` value:

  `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B${Lrow+1};DataBase!A2:B250;2;0);"")`

In this way you don't need two different arrays (`data1` and `data2`) because the data can be pasted directly into the sheet:

```
const vlp_form = `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B${Lrow+1};DataBase!A2:B250;2;0);"")`;
const data = [DateEntry, username ,vlp_form, ArrivalTime, ExitTime, new Date()];
webAppSheet1.getRange(Lrow+1,1, 1, data.length).setValues([data]);
```

I changed your formula to match the `DataBase` sheet from `BBDD` to `DataBase`. Change that back (in the script) if you are using the other sheet name.

### Solution:

Modify only `AddRecord` as follows:

```
function AddRecord(DateEntry, username, ArrivalTime, ExitTime ) {
  
  // get spreadsheet details
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fjpKRi3k0VQ8MOoa5ruCZurXcz6vmVsQt2g3NbELSJA/edit#gid=';
  //Paste URL of GOOGLE SHEET
  const ss1= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  const webAppSheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName('ReceivedData');

  const Lrow = webAppSheet1.getLastRow();
  const vlp_form = `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B${Lrow+1};DataBase!A2:B250;2;0);"")`;
  const data = [DateEntry, username ,vlp_form, ArrivalTime, ExitTime, new Date()];

  webAppSheet1.getRange(Lrow+1,1, 1, data.length).setValues([data]); 
    
}
```

**Be careful:**

- In order for the changes to take effect you need to re-deploy your
  webApp (either new deployment in the new script editor) or if you are
  using the older editor, deploy the web app again by selecting project
  version new and click on update.

Also don't forget to save the script changes.